# Parsing CSV into a POJO list with Jackson CSV

Tags: java, csv, jackson, jackson-dataformat-csv

I have a string, which contains CSV data and would like to parse this into a list of POJOs.

How can I do this with Jackson CSV?

Bonus: How can I make it so that it uses CSV headers?

---

My two unsuccessful attempts:

```
CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
// First attempt 
CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(POJO.class); 
// Second attempt
CsvSchema schema =  CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();

System.out.println(schema.usesHeader());
String content = new String(inputFile.getBytes());
MappingIterator<POJO> it = mapper.readerFor(POJO.class).with(schema).readValues(content);

return it.readAll();
```

The first attempt populated the attributes in a random order which was not the in the order of the CSV columns, or in the order of attributes of the POJO.

The second attempt gave the following error:

```
Unrecognized field "﻿attribute2" (class uk.ac.packagename.POJO), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: "attribute2", "﻿attribute3", "﻿attribute4", "﻿attribute5", "﻿attribute6", "attribute1"]) at [Source: java.io.StringReader@617bb5db; line: 2, column: 14] (through reference chain: uk.ac.packagename.POJO["attribute2"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that, because my CSV was coming from a MultipartFile as part of a file upload, an invisible character was being added to the front. (don't know why though)

I fixed this by filtering the raw CSV string for non-alphanumeric characters:

```
content.replaceAll("^[\\W]","");
```

Then the method marked as "Second attempt" worked perfectly.